# ¿Por qué no funciona jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css3

Tengo un problema con el botón `hamburguesa`. Cuando sobrepongo el puntero del mouse no se aplica el estilo *CSS*, y por lo tanto tampoco funciona el *jQuery* para abrirlo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer funcionar el botón `hamburguesa`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".c-hamburger").click(function() {
    $("#hamb-nav").toggle(100);
  });
});

$(".c-hamburger").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("c-hamburger--htx");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
}

#top-bar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#hamb-icon {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 15px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#hamb-icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamb-nav {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#hamb-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 15px 30px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#hamb-nav ul li {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

#mid-bar {
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#mid-bar h1 {
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 30pt;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}


/*hamburger menu icon*/

.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #A4A4A4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -8px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -8px;
}


/*hamburger menu icon when open*/

.c-hamburger--htx {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>dive</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top-bar">
    <div id="hamb-icon">
      <button class="c-hamburger">
      <span></span>
   </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav id="hamb-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Nav</li>
      <li>Nav</li>
      <li>Nav</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="mid-bar">
    <h1>DIVE</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por favor cambia tu pregunta en español

Comment: Formula bien tu pregunta, que es lo que falla? que pretendes con este codigo? estructuralo.

Comment: no esta funcionando jquery, no puedo encontrar dónde esta el error. necesito hacer un toggle entre clases para que el icono de menu muestre el menú y a su vez cambie de tres rayas a una equis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica los `z-index` de `#mid-bar` y `#ham-icon`, con eso debería funcionar

Esto es un problema cuando usas `position` en algún elemento y esto tiende a sobreponer el elemento sobre otro elemento, entonces estas dos reglas deberian quedarte algo así.

```
#mid-bar {
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;

  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#hamb-icon {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 15px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```